# data structure for representing non square board game

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, game-engine, graph-algorithm, chess

I am trying to design a board game, which is not square. Here we have 2 different types of pieces(attacker & defenders). Both can move to any adjacent free intersection.  The attacker player can also jump on defender player if there is empty space in the adjacent intersection in the same line. Considering these cases i can think of storing the board as array.
But this is not a right choice, as i need to harcode attackable position from each indexes. need your suggestions for designing this board.
One more option is using graph and maintain the direction of the node(Left,Right,Top, Down), but this would require 3 Down nodes on the top vertex of the board.
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two times I had to do this, I created a `play_line` data type.  I had the canonical graph with nodes and edges; a `play_line` is a sequence of edges.

A legal move to a free, adjacent intersection is a trivial property from the graph alone.  A piece `A` at node `m` can move to any node `n` where

- edge (m,n) exists
- node `n` is empty

A jump from `m`, over `n`, to `p` exists where

- edge (m,n) exists
- edge (n,p) exists
- node `n` contains a piece `D` (defender)
- node p is empty
- Along the `play_line` containing edge (m,n), (n,p) is the next edge on that line.

Does that help?

---

**Update after OP comment**

There is nothing to maintain for the `play_line` objects, as the lines of play do not change once initialized.  These are hard-coded from the game board, an enhancement of the graph.  For instance if the board is labeled

```
    a
b c d e f
g h i j k
l m n o p
  q r s
```

then the first full row is a line of play containing five nodes in order, `[b, c, d, e, f]`.  There are corresponding graph edges (correct by construction) of `(b, c), (c, d), (d, e), (e, f)`.  Note that your code must either traverse this in either direction, or you make a second `play_line` in the reverse order.

Comment: Can you breif how play_line data maintained? 
Is it like sequence containing  possible 2 edge. 
Like each element in sequence is a pair of edges (m,n) and (n,p).